# Server with multiple projects in /var/www?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I have a server that I want to use as a personal server, with all of my projects under `/var/www`.

I currently have two folders, `/var/www/html` and `/var/www/site`.

I want to be able to access these folders by the following URLs (`123.123.123.123` is my server IP):

`123.123.123.123/html` and `123.123.123.123/site`

Here is my `default` virtual host file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 123.123.123.123;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

And here is the one I created for `/var/www/site`, called `site`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # Because this site uses Laravel, it needs to point to /public
    root /var/www/site/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 123.123.123.123;

    location /site {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

But when I go to `123.123.123.123/site`, it says 404 Not Found, so clearly I'm doing something wrong (and yes, I restarted nginx).

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one `server` block, as both `/html` and `/site` live in the same `server`.

Use `nginx -t` to check that `nginx` really does restart without giving any errors.

As `/site` uses a complicated directory scheme, you will need to use a nested `location` block to get the paths correct.

Your first project seems to have a simple arrangement of static and PHP files. You can use a `root /var/www;` statement to map URIs beginning with `/html` to the `html` folder. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for more.

Something like this may work for you:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ^~ /site {
        alias /var/www/site/public;
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /site/index.php last; }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
}
```

The default server does not need a `server_name`.

Comment: I have one problem. If I go to a certain route, like `123.123.123.123/site/search`, it returns a 404, but the index (`123.123.123.123/site`) works fine. What should I do to fix this so the routing works as it should? In case it helps, here's the `.htaccess` file: https://pastebin.com/LMXK6vjQ

Comment: I cannot see anything strange in the `.htaccess` file. Basic checks: clear browser cache, test configuration using `nginx -t` and/or `nginx -T`, and look at the access and error logs to find out what is happening.